# In the example of std::atomic<T>::exchange, why the count of times is not 25?

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

The example I talked about is [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange) on cppreference.com.
The code snippet is pasted below.

```
int main(){
    const std::size_t ThreadNumber = 5;
    const int Sum = 5;
    std::atomic<int> atom{0};
    std::atomic<int> counter{0};
 
    // lambda as thread proc
    auto lambda = [&](const int id){
        for (int next = 0; next < Sum;){
            // each thread is writing a value from its own knowledge
            const int current = atom.exchange(next);
            counter++;
            // sync writing to prevent from interrupting by other threads
            std::osyncstream(std::cout)
                << '#' << id << " (" << std::this_thread::get_id()
                << ") wrote " << next << " replacing the old value "
                << current << '\n';
            next = std::max(current, next) + 1;
        }
    };
 
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ThreadNumber; ++i){
        v.emplace_back(lambda, i);
    }
 
    for (auto& tr : v){
        tr.join();
    }
 
    std::cout << ThreadNumber << " threads adding 0 to "
              << Sum << " takes total "
              << counter << " times\n";
}
```

To me, the value of `counter` is 25 because 5 threads and each thread loops 5 times. However, the shown output is 16. I also ran it myself, the possible value varies, but it never gets to be 25.

Why the printed value of counter is actually smaller?

Comment: "_each thread loops 5 times._": What are you basing this on? The loop variable is modified only in `next = std::max(current, next) + 1;`. How do you immediately get from this that the loop iterates `5` times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider one of the possible executions:

Lets say one of the threads finishes the loop before other threads start.

This gives you `atom == 4`. The next thread to enter the loop will get `current == 4` and will exit the loop after the first iteration.

This way the second thread increments `current` once instead of 5 times like you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't taken the trouble to analyse the code in detail, but the `for` loop in the lambda is broken (or, at least, not doing what you are expecting it to do).  If you replace it with something more straightforward, namely:

```
for (int next = 0; next < Sum; ++next){
```

then [25 is output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JMd99KmTt7u7RTUH).

Comment: @user17732522 Smarter than me as always :)  And late here, tired...

Comment: Actually, I am also guilty of not fully reading your answer, missing the "_(or, at least, not doing what you are expecting it to do)_" part. Yes, it is not really broken, but maybe unexpected.

Comment: @user17732522 Obscure, certainly.